# How would I create C# Object with this JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

How would I create C# class to deserialize this?

```
{"result":{"appid":295110,"contextid":1,"items":{"Skin: Graffiti Hunting Rifle":11990}}}
```

With all the online converters the ":" after Skin messes it up.

Comment: Check this http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [Json.NET](http://Json.net)

```
string result = "{'result':{'appid':295110,'contextid':1,'items':{'Skin: Graffiti Hunting Rifle':11990}}}";
var jsonData = JObject.Parse(result);
MessageBox.Show(jsonData["result"]["appid"].ToString());
```

Comment: I meant what do I put for the class, because im doing it from a webpage

Comment: @DylanBro Using Json.NET link added.

Comment: Not working, it doesnt find json.appid

Comment: @DylanBro Sorry I did not test, the latest code example works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following thread:
http://json2csharp.com/
thank you